# Remove all references to removed Sql Server database

Tags: database, sql-server

One of my programs that I have written, creates on installation a SQL Server database. The database name
is hardcoded in the sources. Now I have the problem, that on a clients machine
the program was de-installed and the database was deleted manually (all I know is that the MDF file not more exists). And at re-installation we get a SQL Server error "Database already exists".

All files are removed and also in SQL Management Studio the database is not
more visible. I tried to create a new database with the same name in SQL Management Studio and I get the same error.

In the next version of my program I will make the db name configurable. But what can I do meanwhile, to remove any existing link / reference to the broken / wrongly removed database?

Comment: If you try `SELECT name,filename FROM master.sys.sysdatabases`, does your "deleted" database appear in the list?

Comment: @BillP3rd : Yes, it does!!! So I deleted it, and now it does not appear anymore. But the original error remains. What can I do next?

Comment: Where all does your installation process you built reference the DB that it's finding as already existing? If it's not in the ODBC entries (per below answer) or on a locally installed SQL instance, then it's in the registry or where ever your installation logic/code is doing that check so to get an accurate answer, check your code at the installation package level, & then remove that reference that causes this installation error. I assume your process DOES not try to create a new DB on a remote SQL Server instance where multiple clients connect as that could be an issue with a shared SQL DB.

Comment: First, what command(s) did you use to delete the database? Did you do it within SQL or just delete the files from the file system? The "standard" way to force a database to be dropped is:

`ALTER DATABASE [YourDatabaseName] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;`
`DROP DATABASE [YourDatabaseName];`

I would also suggest `SELECT * FROM sys.databases` and `SELECT * FROM master.sys.master_files` to see more of what SQL thinks is going on.

Comment: You might also do `DBCC CHECKDB` in the `[master]` database to see if it detects any inconsistencies.

Answer (score 1):

Check for and delete any references to your database from the ODBC Data Sources Administrator control panel.

I'm not sure if your source will be in the 32-bit or 64-bit settings. Depending on your database source you may only be able to delete it from the 32-bit or 64-bit control panels.

To launch the 32-bit control panel right-click your start button, then click "run" and enter:

```
%systemdrive%\Windows\SysWoW64\Odbcad32.exe
```

For 64-bit:

```
%systemdrive%\Windows\System32\Odbcad32.exe
```

Alternatively you can find them in the (old) Control Panel under Administrative Tools.

Locations for ODBC Data Source Administrator according to [this page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/942976).